# GWT: How to change window.confirm Ok/Cancel to Yes/No

Tags: gwt

I am using a [Window.confirm()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#confirm%28java.lang.String%29) in my GWT application, the message I see is *"Ok"* and *"Cancel"*

Instead of *"Ok"* I want *"Yes"* and instead of *"Cancel"* I want *"No"*, is it possible?

Can a user see *"Yes"*, *"No"*  instead of *"OK"*, *"Cancel"* in a popup displayed after calling `Window.confirm()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.
But you can use your own confirm-like widget. Just remember that it will never be blocking like `window.confirm`.